# What is the origin of the name Nilfgaard?

Tags: name-significance, polish-language, the-witcher, andrzej-sapkowski

The empire of Nilfgaard becomes very important in the Witcher saga starting from the end of *Sword of Destiny* and continuing through the novels starting with *Blood of Elves*. The name has always intrigued me (and slightly confused me as I never remember whether it's Nilfgaard or Niflgaard). It looks Scandinavian, with "aa" often being used as an anglicisation of the Scandinavian letter [å](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85) and [gård](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/g%C3%A5rd) being a common Scandinavian suffix, but is Nilfgaard in the books written to resemble any Scandinavian culture? The name seems to be preserved by translation, being [the same in the original Polish](https://wiedzmin.fandom.com/wiki/Nilfgaard); does it have a Scandinavian ring to the Polish-speaking eye too, or does it mean/suggest something in the Polish language?

**What is the origin and significance of the name Nilfgaard?**

Comment: Maybe its related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niflheim ?

Comment: @kimchilover  you are almost certainly right. I've just read an old interview with Sapkowski - he admits that he really likes borrowing names from older languages, like Brythonic. Using Old Norse would be in his style.

Comment: Mhm, it looks like Niflheim and Midgard combined.

Comment: So it does.  Which would point to Scandinavian.